# Input of type date time disabling dates until current date

Tags: javascript, asp.net-core, calendar

I have this calendar and I want to disable all dates until current date:

In my html

```
<div>
    <input asp-for="SelectedDate" id="SelectedDate"/>
</div>
```

In my js file

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var date = new Date();
    var currentMonth = date.getMonth();
    var currentDate = date.getDate();
    var currentYear = date.getFullYear();
    
    var minDate = new Date(currentMonth, currentDate, currentYear);
    
    $("#SelectedDate").attr("min", minDate);
});
```

Backend:

```
[BindProperty]
public DateTime SelectedDate { get; set; }
```

I have to mention that I am using Razor Pages .Net Core.

The issue is that the min attribute is not working. I tried adding it in my html for a test like this but had no effect:

```
<input asp-for="SelectedDate" id="SelectedDate" min="05/11/2021"/>
```

Is there any workaround so that I can disable all dates untill the current date?

EDIT

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this [article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/datetime-local) you can see if you want to set min and max time, you need follows the format `yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm`,and must have both `min` and `max`.

So you can change your code like below.

```
<input asp-for="SelectedDate" min="@DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm")"  max="2050-06-01T00:00" />
```

Comment: Ok so your suggestion makes that a validation message appears if the user chooses a date that is not in the range, so I guess that I should use a css file to make the dates disabled in the calendar? Because I don 't want an english warning message since my site is in another language

Comment: This is not the case. My solution will disable other dates. You can try it.

Comment: In my browser id does not, I tried on Edge and Chrome. It appears a validation message but the dates are still selectable

Comment: Yes, I edited my post with a picture where I show the message

Comment: You can see my [test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fg33k.gif).

Comment: I wrote the same line of code but in my case that message appears and the dates are still selectable. From the article you sugested I saw that it depends on the browser how it will handle it

Comment: If this is the case, I suggest you use [datepicker](https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/)